# C# Serial DataReceived event starved

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I am building on top of an existing application and using the C# SerialPort class to handle data transactions over USB. I've noticed that when the application spawns a number of long-running threads and does not specify them as long-running using the TaskCreation LongRunning option, these threads can temporarily starve the SerialPort DataReceived event and prevent it from triggering for some extended amount of time.

Is this some fundamental result of the way in which C# handles thread management?

Is there any way to increase the "priority" of the DataReceived event?

If not, would a "solution" be to have a constantly running thread that polls the serial port data flags rather than using the DataReceived event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty fundamental, yes.  Your DataReceived event handler is called by a thread-pool thread.  When you've got too many of them active for other purposes, like Tasks that are not LongRunning, then it can be a while before your event handler gets a shot at running.  The normal operating system scheduling algorithm that boosts a thread's priority when it completes an I/O call is ineffective here, it only gets the tp thread scheduled efficiently :)

This is a fundamental fire-hose problem, you are expecting the machine to accomplish more work than it can perform.  The ballpark way to know if you are doing it right is by looking at Task Manager.  CPU usage should be pegged at 100%.  If it is substantially less then you are not using the thread-pool efficiently, *some* tasks are hogging the pool but are not executing enough code, typically because they are waiting too much on a sync object or an I/O operation to complete.  You ought to fix that, either by using a plain Thread or with TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning.  ThreadPool.SetMinThreads() is often quoted as a quick fix, it is a dirty one.  Upgrading the machine spec, more cores, is a cleaner one.

Comment: Thanks for the post. It's unfortunate because I believe most of the active threads are not using the thread-pool efficiently or executing much code, but a result of poor code. Would you have any suggestions for using the DataReceived event knowing this, or is the answer "fix the other code that's spawning so many inefficient threads"?

Comment: I covered this in the post, you know what to do :)

Answer (score 1):

There's an even simpler solution -- use the serial port the way the device driver writers intended.  There is absolutely nothing about serial port communications that warrants use of a worker thread, either manually created or from the thread pool.  I encourage you to read my entire blog post ["If you *must* use .NET System.IO.Ports.SerialPort"](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport), but the short version is to use `BaseStream.ReadAsync` with `async`+`await` if you are on a recent version of .NET, and `BaseStream.BeginRead` with a callback otherwise.

Also, thanks for providing me with yet another reason the `DataReceived` event is horrible.  The list is getting quite long.

Comment: I hope there's some explanation for the downvote coming, even if it is just "I hate it when people link to their own blog".  If there's some technical argument, I'm open to discussing it, but I've had quite a lot of experience with serial port programming, so discussion is probably going to end up with more explanation of why I stick by my recommendation.